# Table of Identifiers

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I need to make a table of identifiers using the method - a combination of a binary tree and hash addressing, but I can not find the information on this method. Could you suggest where I can find information on this method or simple example in C/C++ or another programming language.
.

Comment: If you're required to use a certain technique, then that suggests this is for homework. If you're being asked to implement a symbol table, then haven't you already learned about them in class? Information on this method can be found in your textbook or from your instructor.

Comment: Also, if this is homework it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store a table of identifiers using a [hash table](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) or [tree structure?](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html)